# Deploy a spring boot JAR to Azure Web Services with Gradle

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot

I  prefer to use gradle with Spring Boot. I have found resources about deploying to Azure with the Maven Plugin for Azure App Service Web Apps. How would one take an approach with gradle as a build system?

Comment: Why it should matter? You just build jars and deploy them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to separate deployment and build.

You can use Azure build pipeline task to build with [gradle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops).

Part of that build you can [create artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) which contains your app

Then create release which will deploy jars to azure app service